# Jenkins Build Issue with Xamarin Project

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, msbuild

I have setup a xamarin project with Jenkins and using a Mac to build

```
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/nuget restore TheProject/TheProject.sln
```

I am using the above command and its failing

```
   MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.0' from '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/'.
   MsBuild.exe does not exist at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/xbuild.exe'.
```

Its not with the command but I feel its something in the code - Can someone help please

Comment: Check what is the Mono version installed on that Mac `mono --version`. You have to use a latest release, so as to have MSBuild there.

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 5.8.0.108

Comment: I am also facing same issue. can anyone please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue, I am able to build it from Terminal but not from Jenkins. Is there a solution for this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the issue with me was the $PATH variable being blank in Jenkins Shell.
For ex: in terminal, it had "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands" in it where as if I print $PATH from Jenkins, it was blank.

Appending the mono command path "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands" to $Path using below command worked for me.

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:$PATH
```